# Jquery timepicker with datepicker not working no error in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

No errors occur in the error console, time-picker displays good  but date-picker is not being displayed ? What would be the problem ? All 4 alerts are also being displayed without any problem , but datepicker doesn't pops up.

**..........loaded files for datepicker here..............**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery_1_1_3(function($) {


  alert('Load date');



    $(".datepicker").datepicker({

        changeMonth: true,

        changeYear: true

    });

          alert('End date loading...');




});




</script>
```

**..........loaded files for timepicker here..............**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">


    jQuery_1_3_2(function($) {


              alert('Load time');



       $('.timepicker').timepicker({

                                        showPeriod: true,
                                        showLeadingZero: true

                                    });

        alert('End time loading...');

    });




    </script>
```

Comment: please add code in plunker/jsfiddle

Comment: @NitishKumar : there are dependent files of js and css , what about them?

Comment: replace $ to jQuery_1_3_2 and check

Comment: i have updated the post ..please go through again

Comment: Please show exactly which datepicker and timepicker files are being loaded. Without the complete code showing the problem, this question will be difficult to answer.

Comment: am using the jquery datepicker and the timepicker is from here : http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  jQuery_1_3_2(function($) { // change jQuery_1_1_3 tojQuery_1_3_2


  alert('Load date');



    $(".datepicker").datepicker({

        changeMonth: true,

        changeYear: true

    });

          alert('End date loading...');




});




</script>
```